# PHP file upload change file name keep extension

Tags: php, html, css, file-upload, upload

I would like to change the name of files uploaded, for example if i choose to upload file "image.png" i would like to rename this to "face.png" when uploaded.

I have a php image upload form, however it keeps the current name of the file and uploads it, I for now would like a variable name $custom_name which i can edit the contents and this is the new name of the file.

PHP UPLOAD FORM :

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  $errors= array();

  $custom_name = ""; // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO INSERT NEW NAME 

  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("png");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
    $errors[]='Only PNG files';
    echo "Only PNG files";
  }

  if($file_size > 2097152){
     $errors[]='Larger than 2MB';
    echo "Larger than 2MB";
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/quads/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
  }
}
```

I have tried concatenation however just dont know where to place the $custom_name variable.

Thankyou very much for any help

Comment: Do you understand what each part of the code does? Where exactly your problem is?

Comment: @Dekel Hi, the code was from a online tutorial, i have spent a good hour reading about php file upload and believed i would need to change this $file_name = $custom_name . $_FILES['image]['name']; however this didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since you said you already tried (and it looks like you really have), here is an explanation:

When you upload a file in PHP, the original filename goes to `$_FILES['image']['name']`. In your code you set this value to the variable `$file_name`.
You already have the extension of the file in `$file_ext`, so you can use it.

If you have a specific string in the `$custom_name` variable, you can use:

```
$file_name = $custom_name . $file_ext;
```

The second parameter of `move_uploaded_file` is the path of the new file that you want to create (which in your example is `"images/quads/".$file_name`). If the variable `$file_name` will contain the `$custom_name` and the `$file_ext` - you will get what you want.